# ANT execute "npm run build" command

Tags: javascript, ant

I would like to modify ANT file to build javascript files using npm run build as what I usually did at visual studio code.

But it will have error => 'program' is a required attribute of <exec ... />

```
<target name ="npm-build">
<exec dir="${base}" executable="ng.cmd" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="build"/>
</exec>
</target>
```

Can help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Modify <exec dir to <exec program